Have problem with laravel/sanctum unauthenticated
I am practicing with laravel/sanctum, I am making the request to localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie to get the X-XSRF-TOKEN token, and I get the successful request and I get the cookie, now I am making the request to localhost:8000/api/user and I get message:unauthenticated. what am I doing wrong?
Version of laravel 11
.env
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=locahost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1

config/sanctum.php
 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

Routes/api.php
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->all();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');




This is normal, where's the login API ? How could you be authenticated while you are not logged in ?
/sanctum/csrf-cookie is for  CSRF Protection,

is it necessary to login to give me the token in the cookies? because I am currently using sanctum/csrf-cookie and what I get back is the set cookie and I am making the request. @ibra

It seems to me like you are properly authenticated, your actual error code is 401 Unauthorized, which means you are authenticated, but not authorized to do a certain action.
Are you using a FormRequest? If so, make sure to properly handle the Authorization. For example:
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

Please review your routes file, check what method is being called for what Controller, review if any authorization policy middlewares are being used.
Make sure that the authentication guard for sanctum is correct in the config/sanctum.php file:
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

To debug further, you could review the Kernel.php file (if you're using Laravel 11, you'd need to look at bootstrap/app.php
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(
        except: ['stripe/*']
    );
 
    $middleware->web(append: [
        EnsureUserIsSubscribed::class,
    ])
})


@ibra https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

thanks for the answer however I am not logging in I just made the request to sanctum/csrf-cookie since in the documentation I have to make the request to that link and then grab the cookie to make those requests since according to the frameworks like angular and vue they do it automatically.
